# CMIS Metadata Query using C#

Tags: c#, .net, alfresco, cmis

How do you query the alfresco repository by the description?  Or can you point me towards a better option.

I've tried this.

```
IItemEnumerable<IQueryResult> qr = session.Query("SELECT * FROM  cmis:document WHERE cmis:description = 'TEST'", false);
```

I am able to find all document.. or even documents that contain particular names.
Like this

```
IItemEnumerable<IQueryResult> qr = session.Query("SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('~cmis:name:RPT')", false);
```

The value is there

cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:description" displayName="Description" localName="description" queryName="cmis:description">
       TEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
IItemEnumerable<IQueryResult> qr = session.Query("SELECT * FROM cmis:document as " + 
                              "D JOIN cm:titled as T on D.cmis:objectId = T.cmis:objectId " +
                                "WHERE T.cm:description like '%test%'", false);
```